# python3 requsts failing while simple curl command works

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I getting issue while running a python script which is conversion of below provided `curl` command.

Curl commands works without any issues while python scripts fails, while everything is same..

**Simple curl command Below:**

```
curl -vv  -X POST -H "x-api-key: xyz" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"projectName": "dbdisk01", "siteName": "EMEA", "disks": [ "dbdisk01" ], "emailAddress": "dbinfo@somedomain.com"}' \
  https://netvpc.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/v1/archive
```

**Python script:**

```
$ cat post_jobs
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

# Constants
api_key="xyz"
api_url="https://netvpc.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/v1/archive"

# User input
project_name = input("Enter projectName: ")
site_name = input("Enter siteName: ")
email_address = input("Enter emailAddress: ")
disk_file_or_volume = input("Enter the path to the file containing disk names (press Enter if providing a single volume): ")

if disk_file_or_volume:
    with open(disk_file_or_volume, 'r') as file:
        volumes = [line.strip() for line in file]
else:
    volumes = [input("Enter volume name: ")]

# Create JSON payload in Python
json_payload = {
    "projectName": project_name,
    "siteName": site_name,
    "disks": volumes,
    "emailAddress": email_address
}

headers = {"x-api-key": api_key, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
response = requests.post(api_url, json=json_payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

**Execution & results:**

```
$ ./post_jobs
Enter projectName: dbdisk01
Enter siteName: EMEA
Enter emailAddress: dbinfo@somedomain.com
Enter the path to the file containing disk names (press Enter if providing a single volume):
Enter volume name: dbdisk01
{"Error": "Invalid Request. {'Status': 'Invalid Request : Unidentified disk name with no volume association. Please verify request!'}"}
```

Comment: You should probably hard code the values you expect and see if that works. Then try doing it with the user input.

Comment: @matt, thanks for the input but hard coding values also giving same error.

Comment: It would be good to put the values into your question so we can compare the curl call and the requests call.